# nothing shows with the now on air script

Tags: php, air

I Have an on air script. I want to show who now on air. I have this script:

```
<?php

putenv("TZ=Europe/Amsterdam");
$h = date('G');
$d = date('w');

// Sunday
if ($d == 0 && $h >= 0 && $h < 9) { // Show Runs From Midnight til 6am
    $djname = 'Kick Radio'; //DJ Name
    $show = 'Kick Non Stop'; // Show description
}
elseif ($d == 0 && $h >= 0 && $h < 10) { // Show Runs From Midnight til 6am
    $djname = 'Kick Radio'; //DJ Name
    $show = 'Sunday Morning Songs'; // Show description
}
elseif ($d == 0 && $h >= 10 && $h < 0) { // Show Runs From Midnight til 6am
    $djname = 'Kick Radio'; //DJ Name
    $show = 'Kick Non Stop'; // Show description
}


// Monday
if ($d == 1 && $h >= 0 && $h < 0) { // Show Runs From Midnight til 6am
    $djname = 'Kick Radio'; //DJ Name
    $show = 'Kick Non Stop'; // Show description
}

echo '<h3>'.$show.'</h3>';
```

But it didn't show something. Only the `<h3>` tags. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You should also look into the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem is you give a chance to Sun `$d == 0` and Mon `$d == 1` only. You need conditions for other days of week too
2. Hours $h can't be `>= 0` & `< 0` same time. So your 3rd and 4th conditions are impossible

Start with following code

```
    if ($d == 0 && $h >= 0 && $h <= 6) {
        // Sunday midnight - 6 a.m.
    }
    elseif ($d == 0) {
        // remaining hours of Sunday
    }
```